# Prepend to RPATH

Tags: cmake

After building with CMake on Linux (but before installing), all the linked libraries are added to the final executable's RPATH.

However, I would like to *prepend* `$ORIGIN/../lib:` to this RPATH.

So far, I've only been able to *replace* the RPATH, and that's not what I want: I want `ld.so` to first look in `../lib`. This is what I currently do:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
  INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib:...")
```

While this works, it's missing some additional third-party libraries that are not part of my build tree, and who are not located in system directories.

Doing `chrpath -l foo` gives me the exact same `INSTALL_RPATH` above. If I don't set those properties, I get the long list of DSO locations, e.g. `RPATH=/bar/baz/:/quux/` etc. (the one I'd like to prepend to).

I've tried using `get_property(_existing_rpath foo INSTALL_RPATH)`, but that gives me an empty string

I've read the hints at https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling and noticed under "CMake Bugs" that

> At least on CMake 2.6.4 RHEL5, man cmakecommands for
>   INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH pretends that this setting will **append** the
>   link path to any CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH content one specified. However,
>   on this version, enabling INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH will **replace** it.
>
> Well, not so sure about this any more: just verified this on CMake
>   2.8.0, and now on *both* versions it does list correct changes in cmake_install.cmake. This bug may have occurred due to previously not
>   doing per-target install(), or perhaps due to some other changes in
>   CMake RPATH-related variables.

By the way, I'm only interested in getting a working RPATH for the *built* files, as in before having run install. I haven't configured the installation properly (added install targets and so on). Do I need to look into that part for this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can't find answers on Google, it's often the case that the answer is obvious. This seems to work just fine:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE
  INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE
  INSTALL_RPATH "\$ORIGIN/../lib:${INSTALL_RPATH}")
```

On my system (and CMake 3.6.1), it seems `INSTALL_RPATH` begins with a colon, but I wouldn't count on it. Also, since I'm obviously setting the *global* `INSTALL_RPATH` here, it *may* be overspecified (I haven't checked).

Comment: if you get upvote on stack overflow, it's often the case that other think the answer is non-obvious.